# ... diese EINGABE, selbst ein Akt der Freiheit

Tags: meaning

In the below text

*Das, als was das System sich so wiederfindet, oder vielmehr wozu es sich selbst gemacht hat, ist, insofern es ein Bestimmtes ist, einerseits wieder ein Endliches, gewissermaßen ein Bedingtes.  Aber es ist jetzt erstens nur von der logischen Entwickelung des Absoluten bedingt; es ist ein göttlicher Beruf, der dadurch zu uns laut wird.  Es bedarf immer einer Hingabe, eines Opfers; denn die erkannte logische Nothwendigkeit ist kein Zwang; dem göttlichen Berufe in dieser Form kann widerstanden werden; aber es ist leicht einzusehen, daß diese **Eingabe**, selbst ein Akt der Freiheit, eben zur wahren Freiheit führt.  Mag die Aufgabe, die uns auf diese Weise gestellt wird, noch so gering erscheinen — nur etwa die Durchführung eines einzelnen Gedankens: — wir wissen doch, daß dieser Gedanke eben an der Zeit ist und seine ewige Geltung behauptet, weil er, aus dem Schooße des Absoluten geboren, selbst das Absolute einschließt und aus sich zu entwickeln bestimmt ist.*

I do not grasp the meaning of "Eingabe"? None of the synonyms listed in

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Eingabe#synonyme

seems to fit into the text?

Comment: The original has *Hingabe*, not *Eingabe*.

Comment: Falls sich jemand für die Quelle interessiert: Monrad, "Das Problem der Philosophie und seine geschichtliche Evolution", zweite Hälfte, [Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=BYRAAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA2-PA52&q=%22da%C3%9F%20diese%20Hingabe%22).

Comment: Well, thats not the poster to blame, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Right the first entry on that link is what is meant here:

> an eine Behörde gerichtete schriftliche **Bitte**, Beschwerde o. Ä.; **Petition, Gesuch**

Since it is addressed to God, *Beschwerde* does not really fit, and you never correspond with him in written, so *schriftlich* does not fit either, but *Bitte*, *Petition* or *Gesuch* is a good translation for *Eingabe* in this context.

Comment: It's *Hingabe* as you can read in the [source](https://books.google.de/books?id=BYRAAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA2-PA52&q=%22da%C3%9F%20diese%20Hingabe%22) that David Vogt [found](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54577/diese-eingabe-selbst-ein-akt-der-freiheit#comment133386_54577).